# Can we have Tchebysheff's equality?

Tags: probability

Assuming $μ=0$ and $σ=1$, and also that $X$ is symmetric about $μ=0$, Is there a discrete random variable $X$, satisfying the assumptions above, which takes on (not necessarily positive) integer values such that $P(X < k) = 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$ for every positive integer $k$? If so, give an example if not explain why or why not.

Comment: There is a [sharpness of bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds) section on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I don't think a symmetric distribution can have $P(X<1)=0$.

Comment: Condition $P\left\{ X<k\right\} =1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ for positive
integer $k$ gives $P\left\{ X\leq0\right\} =P\left\{ X<1\right\} =0$.
Symmetry then gives $P\left\{ X\geq0\right\} =0$. So no such rv $X$
exists.